# Is there a way to know if my Ruby gem is being used?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I created a Ruby gem and I would like to know if people are using it after they download it.

Comment: Of course it is impossible (unless for example, you make it work only during the person is online and/or is accessing your server).

Comment: You could always search Github to see if it is in anybody's gemfile.

Comment: Write it to send you a text message?

Comment: @msergeant I searched Github, I think no one is using it haha, than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are a number of techniques you could write into your gem, so that your gem will send you a notifications whenever it's being used, including information about the developer using the gem, the time the gem was used, the geographical location, (the code to the app they're developing) etc'...

But there's a good reason why there's no common way of doing that.

On a personal note, if your gem was sending you notifications about it's use, I would stop using it.

Gems aren't the same as applications - they are development tools. As such, it is expected that their code will perform the task for which they were designated and **ONLY** the task for which they were designated.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm just curious because it's my first gem and I have 572 downloads, I was just wondering if they actually use or just install the gem to try it. Either way I feel happy people are curious enough to download it. Thank you :)